# How to DROP COLUMN with ALGORITHM=INSTANT

Tags: mysql

AS described in the MySQL documentation [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-online-ddl-operations.html#online-ddl-column-operations), it should be possible to drop a column instantly with a syntax like this one:

```sql
ALTER TABLE tbl_name DROP COLUMN column_name, ALGORITHM=INSTANT;
```

It is documented that it is only possible with the following constraints:

- Dropping a column cannot be combined in the same statement with other ALTER TABLE actions that do not support ALGORITHM=INSTANT.
- Columns cannot be dropped from tables that use ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED, tables with a FULLTEXT index, tables that reside in the data dictionary tablespace, or temporary tables. Temporary tables only support ALGORITHM=COPY.

Unfortunately, I am unable to use the syntax described above. For example, here is my test code:

```sql
CREATE TABLE MyTable (
  MyPrimaryKey bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  UserId char(36) NOT NULL,
  Username varchar(254) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (MyPrimaryKey),
  UNIQUE KEY IX_UserId (UserId)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

ALTER TABLE MyTable DROP COLUMN Username, ALGORITHM=INSTANT;
```

When I run this against MySQL 8.0.28, I get the following error:

```
Error Code: 1845. ALGORITHM=INSTANT is not supported for this operation. Try ALGORITHM=COPY/INPLACE.
```

Am I doing something wrong or the documentation is missing something?

Note that the `ROW_FORMAT` of my table is `Dynamic`. Here is how I got the row format:

```sql
SELECT table_name, row_format
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema=DATABASE() AND table_name = 'MyTable';
```

Comment: I tested on MySQL 8.0.29, and it works for me without the error. What does `SELECT VERSION();` return on your instance? I'm wondering if your client is 8.0.28 but the server is not.

Comment: As mentionned above, I am using 8.0.28. That's what is being return by `SELECT VERSION();` I looked at the mysql release notes and that feature was added to mysql 8.0.29! https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/8.0/en/news-8-0-29.html

Comment: Life during the MySQL 8.0 era is sure unpredictable!

Answer (score 2):

This functionality has been added to mysql 8.0.29. See the [release notes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/8.0/en/news-8-0-29.html) for more details.